# Why do I have more users logged on than there are?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, login

On an old GNU/Linux Ubuntu box I see something like

```
lorenzo@metropolis:~
    $ w
 09:58:18 up 651 days, 19:30,  5 users,  load average: 0.28, 0.30, 0.24
```

The problem is, I am logged on other three sessions. The number should be four, not five. Any clue why the number of reported users is higher?

Checking lastlog, however, returns a correct value:

```
lorenzo@metropolis:~
    $ sudo last -ain 7 | grep 'still logged in' | wc -l
4
```

[edited] Here is the output of `who`, taken in another occasion but still showing two users, and three reported by `w`

```
lorenzo@metropolis:~
    $ who 
lorenzo  pts/0        Dec 28 13:10 (XXX)
lorenzo  pts/1        Dec 28 13:07 (XXX)
lorenzo@metropolis:~
    $ w
 13:11:15 up 651 days, 22:43,  3 users,  load average: 0.49, 0.40, 0.31
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
lorenzo  pts/0    XXX              13:10    0.00s  0.11s  0.00s w
lorenzo  pts/1    XXX              13:07    3:09m  0.13s  0.13s -bash
```

My paranoid sense is tingling.

[edited] some more commands requested

```
    $ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 8.04 \n \l

    $ dpkg-query -S /usr/bin/w.procps 
procps: /usr/bin/w.procps

    $ dpkg-query -S /usr/bin/who
coreutils: /usr/bin/who
```

Comment: `w` command show you processes, which are running under your rights and on which terminal...

Comment: the first line I reported is shown also with `uptime`

Comment: OK, it's not problem. But under the first line of `w` command you will see lines with processes, which is responsible for your 'logon'. In my case, there is processes `startkde`, `kdeinit`, `bash` and `w`.

Comment: In my opinion you should try using the `who` command it would become more clear.

Comment: I edited my original answer with the output from `who`

Comment: Can you please paste me the output of following commands: `cat /etc/issue` & `dpkg -S /usr/bin/w` & `dpkg -S /usr/bin/who`

Comment: I added the output you requested, but `dpkg -S /usr/bin/w` did not produce anything useful, so I used `dpkg-query`

Comment: 'w' shows all open terminal sessions (I mean for example all tabs in you termanal emaulator)+one session after login, plus session for ssh, session outside your graphics etc

Answer (score 1):

`w` uses `/var/run/utmp` and the `/proc` filesystem (on Linux), recording who is currently logged on.

`last` uses `/var/log/wtmp` (and `/var/log/btmp`), showing how has been logging in. However, not every program will update those files properly, on some systems these files may not even exist.

For example, on my system `w` sees my 5 login-sessions within a single GNU screen session:

```
$ w | tail -n +3 | wc -l
5

$ last | grep -c still\ logged
1
```

Yet `last` only recorded one *active* session. When setting `deflogin=off` in GNU screen, even `w` loses track of the active login sessions and keeps displaying 5 sessions, even though I've just opened another 5 windows in that same screen session.

IOW: use e.g. `ps` to find out how many users are "online", how many shells are open, etc. It will give more accurate results as does not rely on (stale) statfiles like `/var/log/utmp`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `w` returns the Xsession in plus the open terminals

```
$ w
 12:05:40 up  3:47,  2 users,  load average: 0.02, 0.15, 0.16
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
userXX   tty7     :0               08:18    3:47m 13:41   0.00s /bin/sh /etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc -- /etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc
userXX   pts/0    :0.0             12:03    0.00s  0.11s  0.00s w
```

It is why there is one user more.
Do you have the same thing ? Could you give use the complete `w` result, if it is not the case ?

Comment: You haven't understood my question. In fact, your `w` command reports correctly two users, and you have two logged in (one for the X session one the open terminals). In my case, however, I am shown only N-1 users of the N reported in the first line.

Answer (score 0):

when using just 'w' it will display the header plus the command that you are currently launching, so it will always show an additional line where your user appears executing 'w', then it will always show one more line.